# Kafka Zookeeper-less Single node OCI image

Tags: docker, apache-kafka

Is there an official OCI Image (not Docker compose) for a single node kafka without Zookeeper containerized and ready for deployment for test and dev purposes?

Comment: 1) Docker Compose doesn't care if the image is in OCI format. 2) There's no official Kafka image, period. But there's PRs for kraft kafka in the repos for the most frequently downloaded images

Answer (score 0):

Answering the question

This is the closest thing to an answer I found:

https://hub.docker.com/r/bashj79/kafka-kraft

based on an official download...